# Alfresco Share - script tags disappears in ftl

Tags: share, alfresco

I'm trying to customize a panel for a document metadata.  I would show the metadata in three tabs.  For that, I use a yui component tabview. In my config xml, I added:

```
<view-form template="/form/tab-view-form.ftl" />
```

In the ftl, I included a second ftl:

```
<#include "tab-view-form-script.ftl" />
```

This ftl contains the js import, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${url.context}/yui/tabview/tabview.js"></script>
```

When I look in the source code, I don't see a call to these JS.

If I add in this ftl a simple html code (like `<p>test</p>`), I see that.
If I add directly a JavaScript between 2 `<script>` tags, I don't see also.

Why does it behave like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried without the src and directly with the js code in the script tags?

Or width the CDATA

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[

//]]></script>
```

Take a look at the example: **alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/form/invite-response.lib.ftl**

Comment: It should work, take a look at the example script. Or use the example script to test if that one works.